# Is the Open Source Jalopy Eclipse plugin compatible with Ganymede?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, code-formatting, eclipse-3.4, jalopy

After much searching, I found the download for the [eclipse version of jalopy](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=45216). Is this compatible with Eclipse 3.4? It's dated 2006.

I've copied the extracted folder to my plugins directory and  run `eclipse -clean`, but I can't find anything matching 'jalopy' in preferences.

If it's not compatible, are there any (free) alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an update:

Note: the latest eclipse3.5 Galileo [code formatter](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-230.htm) now:

- supports most of Jalopy formatting option.
- has made quite a few improvement on formatters (look for the term 'formatter' in those [building notes of jdt-core](http://giano.com.dist.unige.it/eclipseMirror/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.5.1RC4-200909111628/buildnotes/buildnotes_jdt-core.html).

It also can be run from the [command-line if needed](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-230.htm).

For a specific formatting option which would not be correctly managed by eclipse, you can define a [`codeFormatter` extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_jdt_core_codeFormatter.html?resultof=%22%66%6f%72%6d%61%74%74%65%72%22%20%22%66%6f%72%6d%61%74%74%22%20). More practical details in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975980/how-can-i-use-the-eclipse-indenter-from-my-code).

Answer (score 0):

i'm told that open source version of jalopy is not for commercial use.

eclipse itself has good source code formatting capabilities. Go to java | preferences/settings. type format and you should see the various options.

Comment: Eclipse's code formatter is still getting something wrong for me, hence the need to find an alternative.

Comment: Oh, and the version of the plugin on sourceforge is marked as being under the BSD license, so it's not 'not for commercial use'.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'yes'. Preferences are in `Window > Jalopy Preferences`, and it's run from the right click context menu. Seems a little buggy, though.