# Eclipse JDT: Call 'correct indentation' programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I am working on an Eclipse plugin that modifies Java code in a user's project.

Basically the result of this plugin is that Java annotations are added to some methods, so

```
void foo() { ... }
```

becomes

```
@MyAnnotation
void foo() { ... }
```

Except that it doesn't quite look like that; the indentation on the newly inserted annotation is wack (specifically, the new annotation is all the way to the left-hand side of the line). I'd like to make all my changes to the file, and then programmatically call "Correct Indentation."

Does anyone know how to do this? I can't find the answer here or in the JDT forums, and all the classes that look relevant (IndentAction, JavaIndenter) are in internal packages which I'm not supposed to use...

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a good starting point may be:
org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatterApplication

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I think I may have figured out the solution I want. Guess I should have spend more time searching before asking... but for future reference, here's what I did! The good stuff was in the ToolFactory...

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ToolFactory;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatter;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ISourceRange;
import org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit;

...

ICompilationUnit cu = ...

...

CodeFormatter formatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(null);
ISourceRange range = cu.getSourceRange();
TextEdit indent_edit =
  formatter.format(CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT, 
    cu.getSource(), range.getOffset(), range.getLength(), 0, null);
cu.applyTextEdit(indent_edit, null);

cu.reconcile();
```

This reformats the entire file. There are other options if you need to reformat less...

Comment: i guess this will use the default formatter. have you figured out how to specify another formatter?

Answer (score -1):

It's probably easier to add the indentation as you process the Java code.

Your Eclipse plugin had to read the `void foo() { ... }` line to know to add the `@MyAnnotation`, right?  Just get the indentation from the Java line, and append your annotation to the indentation.

Comment: Thanks Gilbert, but actually I didn't read the line...
I get the method location from 

MethodDeclaration.getStartPosition()

where MethodDeclaration is in the package org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom. Now I could go back and copy what's before the method declaration from the start of the line, but I don't want to copy a bunch of junk if the programmer's using some alternative formatting...

Comment: Ok, I've not seen these org.eclipse.jdt packages before.  How are you adding your annotation to the Java source code?