# Implement Java code formatter in a StyledText area

Tags: java, swt, code-formatting, styledtext

I want to try and implement a key binding much like `Ctrl + i` in eclipse for a `StyledText` area so that the Java code in the area will be formatted correctly.

I've been looking around for a while and can't seem to find much information on how to implement the indentation. Is there a way this can be done without too much fuss? Or will it involve coding my own formatter with a lot of cases to automatically format what the user types into the area?

Comment: Any explanation for the down vote? Down votes aren't very useful if you don't give a reason

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format specifically Java code, you can reuse code from JDT, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2873966/) for an example. But you might have to do some work to apply it to your `StyledText` keeping the styles in order.